# React inside Rails project deploying to Heroku gets an error cp: missing destination file operand after 'es20client/build/.public/'"

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I am a coding bootcamp developer and I have been wrestling with implementing authentication in a web app. I have made applications with API calls but was always learning and practicing other coding concepts. I have found out I can bring my React project inside my Rails project and deploy one full stack project to Heroku. This helped my troubleshooting with secure API calls with sessions and tokens. I am about to begin configuring the project non locally on Heroku and trying to implement the sessions and cookies combo for authentication again.

- root Rails directory package.json
  `{ "name": "heroku-deploy", "descriptions": "Build scripts for Heroku", "engine": { "node": "18.12.1" }, "scripts": { "clean": "rm -rf public", "build": "npm install --prefix es20client && npm run build --prefix es20client", "deploy": "cp -a es20client/build/.public/", "heroku-postbuild": "npm run clean && npm run build && npm run deploy" } }`
- root Rails directory Gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.0.0"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.4"

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem "pg", "~> 1.1"
gem "bcrypt"
# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
# gem "rack-cors"
gem 'active_model_serializers'

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end
```

- root Rails directory /es20client/package.json

```
{
  "name": "es20client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "final-form": "^4.20.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-final-form": "^6.5.9",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "reactjs-popup": "^2.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=4000 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I seem to be getting an error between the project trying to create the production build of the React client and npm running a deploy to copy the contents of es20client/build into public/

The final lines before Build Failed are
"cp: missing destination file operand after 'es20client/build/.public/'"
"Try 'cp --help' for more information."

and running: cp --help

returns:

cp: illegal option -- -
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-aclpsvXx] source_file target_file
cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-aclpsvXx] source_file ... target_directory

Some files attached.

- last of heroku push log

```
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:        
remote:        > heroku-postbuild
remote:        > npm run clean && npm run build && npm run deploy
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > clean
remote:        > rm -rf public
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > build
remote:        > npm install --prefix es20client && npm run build --prefix es20client

...more lines of code...

remote:          npm install -g serve
remote:          serve -s build
remote:        
remote:        Find out more about deployment here:
remote:        
remote:          https://cra.link/deployment
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > deploy
remote:        > cp -a es20client/build/.public/
remote:        
remote: cp: missing destination file operand after 'es20client/build/.public/'
remote: Try 'cp --help' for more information.
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I just needed a space between the "." and "public" in "cp -a es20client/build/.public/" inside of the root Rails package.json. I got a new error and it looks way more friendly.